# Should I use the absolute value of a correlation coefficient?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have calculated the Pearson correlation coefficient for two sets of values using excel. I got the value in the negative number. I know that the idea of getting a negative correlation means that the two variables are reversely proportional. Now, I have to calculate multiple/joint correlation between other variables. Should I use only the absolute value of the first correlation for that case? Or should I use the exact value with the sign? Please guide.

Comment: Usual approach is to use the square of correlation (for some reason called 'coefficient of determination').

Comment: Yes, but when I have to use the r-value, not the squared, then what should I do?

Comment: @LSG I think we need to know more about your use case before we can answer whether you 'should' use the absolute value.